# ISETool.exe The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, isolatedstorage

I am attempting to extract a SQL CE DB from a windows 7.1 phone app running in the emulator using the ISETool and following the docs here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

After launching the app in the emulator I execute the following command at a command prompt;

```
ISETool.exe ts xd 11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555 "C:\Data\My Files"
```

This results in the following error;

```
Download Error. Reason: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution: In the emulator (after the application launches and does whatever you need it to do the DB) close the application and return to the home-screen. Leaving the emulator running then execute the command to extract the files from isolated storage.

Found the simple solution to this here http://strivinglife.com/words/post/Windows-Phone-7-Taking-and-restoring-a-SQL-database.aspx